# Which kernel produces sharper image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

kernel A =

```
[ 0 -1 0
 -1 4 -1 
  0 -1 0 ]
```

and B =

```
[-1 0 -1
  0 4 0
 -1 0 -1 ]
```

i have found the frequency spectrums with freqz2 function of matlab.

A's spectrum has the highest magnitudes in the corners [(1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1),(-1,1) 
and B's in (1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1).

I know that the center of the frequency spectrum has the low frequency information and the corners the high frequency information such as edges. It appears that B filter produces a sharper image although A has higher magnitude in the corners. Why is this happening ?

Comment: You would probably get a better answer at [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definitions it can be seen that `A` tends to sharpen more along the *vertical and horizontal* directions, whereas `B` sharpens more along *diagonals*. Depending on the contents of your image, one effect may be more noticeable than the other.

In frequency terms, if your kernel amplifies certain spatial frequencies at which your image happens not to have much energy, the effect will be hardly noticeable.

Comment: A sharpens more along diagonals and B in vertical and horizontal directions.